# jWebsocket lots of parked threads (WAITING)

Tags: java, multithreading, websocket, threadpool

I'm performing some stress tests (thousands of connections per minute) using the jWebsocket lib in a java server application and after a while the process is completely filled with jWebsocket threads such as the following:

```
"jWebSocket TCP-Engine NIO writer" prio=10 tid=0x0000000000bf6000 nid=0x2eb9 waiting on condition [0x00007f1533bd9000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x000000062ab06e80> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068 )
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

(the output above was retrieved from a thread dump)

Has anyone faced this issue? Any tips to find a solution?

Thanks!

**Edit.**

The big issue is that the threads are never terminated and are kept alive until the application is terminated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a normal situation, your thread pool grew significantly due to a high load and then load went down. In this case most of the threads in pool are waiting for new tasks to come effectively doing nothing.

You can kill idle workers by changing core pool size and max pool size:

```
executor.setCorePoolSize(x);
executor.setMaximumPoolSize(y);
```

Comment: I forgot to mention a very important note :) the threads aren't being destroyed and are kept alive until the application is restarted.

Comment: I provided you "kill" solution just in case it bothers you. What you see is completely normal, threads are waiting for new tasks, feed them work to do and they will start running your tasks